# Eslint Configuration for rule "quotes" is invalid:

Tags: eslint, code-climate

Just trying to set up my site with https://codeclimate.com but getting error when it hits my eslint config settings. Getting an error on my quotes rule which is

```
"quotes": [2,"single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true
      }
]
```

But keep getting the error

```
Error: /code/.eslintrc:
    Configuration for rule "quotes" is invalid:
    Value "[object Object]" must be an enum value.
```

Eslint is version 3.14.0

Any idea what is wrong with the rule ?

Edit to show my versions :

```
"eslint": "3.15.0",
"eslint-loader": "1.6.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the rule, so I guess that it's a version thing and something in your toolchain is using an earlier version of eslint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeClimate uses their own version of ESLint, and not the one specified as a dependency in your package. Here's a link to the documentation that lists version of ESLint that CodeClimate uses: https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/eslint

You have to configure ESLint rules to the version that CodeClimate is running, otherwise you are going to get notification about incorrect configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem today, I used old version of gulp-eslint package (1.1.1)

Comment: Yup I thought of that, but I have all the latest packages.